# Pandas 1.0.1 - how to index a DataFrame with MultiIndex using a list containing a slicer

Tags: pandas, indexing

As a example dataset -

```
In [12]: import numpy as np; import pandas as pd                                                     

In [24]: data_raw = pd.DataFrame([  
    ...:      ...: {'frame': 1, 'face': np.NaN, 'lmark': np.NaN, 'x': np.NaN, 'y': np.NaN},  
    ...:      ...: {'frame': 197, 'face': 0, 'lmark': 1, 'x': 969, 'y': 737},  
    ...:      ...: {'frame': 197, 'face': 0, 'lmark': 2, 'x': 969, 'y': 740},  
    ...:      ...: {'frame': 197, 'face': 0, 'lmark': 3, 'x': 970, 'y': 744},  
    ...:      ...: {'frame': 197, 'face': 0, 'lmark': 4, 'x': 972, 'y': 748},  
    ...:      ...: {'frame': 197, 'face': 0, 'lmark': 5, 'x': 973, 'y': 752},  
    ...:      ...: {'frame': 300, 'face': 0, 'lmark': 1, 'x': 745, 'y': 367},   
    ...:      ...: {'frame': 300, 'face': 0, 'lmark': 2, 'x': 753, 'y': 411},   
    ...:      ...: {'frame': 300, 'face': 0, 'lmark': 3, 'x': 759, 'y': 455},  
    ...:      ...: {'frame': 301, 'face': 0, 'lmark': 1, 'x': 741, 'y': 364},    
    ...:      ...: {'frame': 301, 'face': 0, 'lmark': 2, 'x': 746, 'y': 408},    
    ...:      ...: {'frame': 301, 'face': 0, 'lmark': 3, 'x': 750, 'y': 452}]).set_index(['frame', 'face', 'lmark'])
```

In Pandas 1.0.3, I could filter out rows of the DataFrame above where `lmark` > 3 with the following -

```
data_filtered = data_raw.loc[(slice(None), slice(None), [np.NaN, slice(3)]), :]
```

but in Pandas 1.1.0, the same statement fails with

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'
```

apparently this change is by [design](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/33042).

In that case, how could I filter out rows of the DataFrame below where lmark > 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selecting with `IndexSlice` and `slice` working only in some versions correctly, so I suggest use another approach, selecting by condition(s):

Filtering by [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
vals = [np.nan,1,2,3]
df = data_raw.query('lmark in @vals')
```

Or by [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html):

```
vals = [np.nan,1,2,3]
df = data_raw[data_raw.index.get_level_values('lmark').isin(vals)]
```

If want select all values without `>3`:

```
df = data_raw[~(data_raw.index.get_level_values('lmark') > 3)]
```

Or all values < 3 with missing values:

```
i = data_raw.index.get_level_values('lmark')
df = data_raw[(i <= 3) | i.isna()]
```

Or first 3 rows per first level by [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html):

```
df = data_raw.groupby(level=0).head(3)
```

---

```
print (df)
                      x      y
frame face lmark              
1     NaN  NaN      NaN    NaN
197   0.0  1.0    969.0  737.0
           2.0    969.0  740.0
           3.0    970.0  744.0
300   0.0  1.0    745.0  367.0
           2.0    753.0  411.0
           3.0    759.0  455.0
301   0.0  1.0    741.0  364.0
           2.0    746.0  408.0
           3.0    750.0  452.0
```

Comment: I prefer `df = data_raw[~(data_raw.index.get_level_values('lmark') > 3)]`, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Note: I am not so sure about versions before Pandas 1.0. If you have to deal with versions less than Pandas 1.0, @jezrael's solution is much more stable.

I don't know if this meets your use case, where u want only rows less than 3 on lmark: [Multi-Index Slicing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#using-slicers)

```
#allows for easier slicing than Slice(None)
idx = pd.IndexSlice

#list the data u want to keep ... including np.nan
data_raw.loc[idx[:,:,[np.nan,1,2,3]],:]

                           x    y
frame   face    lmark                   
1        NaN    NaN      NaN    NaN
197     0.0     1.0     969.0   737.0
                2.0     969.0   740.0
                3.0     970.0   744.0
300     0.0     1.0     745.0   367.0
                2.0     753.0   411.0
                3.0     759.0   455.0
301     0.0     1.0     741.0   364.0
                2.0     746.0   408.0
                3.0     750.0   452.0
```

Comment: `data_raw.loc[idx[:,:,:3],:]` filters out rows `lmark` > 3 and `lmark` = np.NaN. I only want to filters out rows `lmark` > 3

Comment: edited the code. lemme know if that's what u have in mind

Comment: @sammywemmy - hmmm, for me your code omit `NaN`s, so also `indexSlice` is version dependend...

Comment: @jezrael, OP is using version 1.1.0. edited the code to include NaN

Comment: this answer is also correct but in the more general case - replacing the slicer with explicit index values such as `[np.nan,1,2,3, ...N]` would be inconvenient.